# Cloud or server to run application

Tags: java, c#, cloud

i'm looking for a free cloud or server where i can run training application of my artificial neural network. I can make app in java or c#, both are simple but training process is long so cloud can't go sleep or turn off. I have dreamspark license on windows azure, but with this license i have nothing to do :/

Comment: This is a recommendation type question and not appropriate for SO

Comment: there was some questions like that and they got answers

Comment: They were probably quite old, and that still doesn't make this question acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote this application as a web application, then it can be easily hosted in Azure. But if it is a desktop application you have to create a virtual machine in azure. But remember it will consume your dreamspark credits. Mostly it is very costly.

With using java I think it is better to use [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/).

Comment: unfortunately, it is desktop application. At this moment i need only run training of network and save result, can i run process on Amazon Web Services until network will be trained? This will take several hours, while application train network. In Azure with dreamspark i can't run WM.

Comment: You can use EC2 virtual servers on cloud. I think it will be able to run little longer time but I haven't tested it's continuity for longer time. anyway I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your a student you should think about running this on Microsoft Azure all Student get a FREE Azure account as part of [DreamSpark.com](http://www.DreamSpark.com) there are loads of learning resources available at [www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com) and [imagine.Microsoft.com](http://imagine.Microsoft.com)

Here are the services which you get for free

Microsoft Azure for DreamSpark gets you started with the services you need to develop in the cloud at no cost:

•Azure App Service Web Apps is a part of a fully managed cloud offering that enables you to build and deploy web apps in seconds. Use ASP.NET, Java, PHP, Node.js or Python. Run popular web apps and CMS solutions. Set up continuous integration and deployment workflows with VSO, GitHub, TeamCity, Hudson or BitBucket – enabling you to automatically build, test and deploy your web app on each successful code check-in or integration tests.

•MySQL Database from ClearDB adds the power of MySQL to your Web Apps. With clearDB MySQL you can deploy more kinds of web apps and CMS solutions such as Wordpress, Joomla, Acquia Drupal, phpBB, and more.

•Application Insights provides a 360° view across availability, performance and usage of your ASP.NET services and mobile applications for Windows Phone, iOS and Android platforms. Search and analyze your data to continuously improve your application, prioritize future investments and improve overall customer experience.

•Visual Studio Online is the fastest and easiest way yet to plan, build, and ship software across a variety of platforms. Get up and running in minutes on our cloud infrastructure without having to install or configure a single server.

Microsoft Azure for DreamSpark is available now for validated DreamSpark students at no cost and no commitment, with no time limit and no accidental charges. You can upgrade to more services later if you want, but you can host your web apps and websites today with the power of the Microsoft cloud behind you and it won’t cost you anything.

You can get more info on how to set this up at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_student_developer_blog/

Comment: thanks for answer. I have account on Microsoft Azure for Students, but this subscription is very limited and i can't run process without virtual machine (and VM is not free). This application must be running continuously for several hours until network will be trained.